# How to get multiple files at node js backend from react frontend i am getting req.files empty

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, multipartform-data, multer

I am Not getting the files at backend which i want to submit in mongodb schema

[this is front end code how i am sending data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfHHd.png)
[it is my backend api where i am getting req.files empty,I ahve tried many thing like upload.array,upload.any,but nothing is working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5fRC.png)

Comment: Code is text and should be submitted as such. You should include a small, reproducible example as a multi-line code block with the "```" tags.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.